# Failed to integrate Ola API in Android

Tags: android, api, curl, sample, unauthorized

I am building an app using Ola API. I've already implemented some of API which doesn't require any kind of authorization(e.g. Simple make a HTTP request and handle JSON response and extract and show important info to the user).

Now, when I'm trying to implement Ola API, the moment I make an HTTP request this shows

```
{"code":"invalid_partner_key","message":"Partner key is not authorized"}
```

I am simply making HTTP request like - https://devapi.olacabs.com/v1/products?pickup_lat=12.9491416&pickup_lng=77.64298

There is nothing coming to authenticate.

How can I do this in an Android HTTP request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending authorization headers using httpUrlConnection in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718785/sending-authorization-headers-using-httpurlconnection-in-android)

Comment: how to make authorization header in android? can you provide some set of resource which can help me to understand?

Comment: Also relevant [cURL to java](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=curl+to+java)

Comment: Click the link. That is your resource.

Comment: thanks a lot..this may help me.

Comment: As far as booking a cab is concerned there already is a [library for that](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to pass credentials for the HTTP in Android I use the `setRequestProperty()`

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) URL.OpenConnection();

Conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization:", Token $SERVER_TOKEN);
```

Comment: Is URL is string of request link to api?

Comment: private final String URL = "http://www.google.com/"; URL url = new URL(URL); HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); .... yeah, URL is a String